# How to full remove a package from the LXTerminal session

Tags: apt, lubuntu

I use Lubuntu 15.04 and I tried to install a software called "AirTime" (Radio Automation for Linux).

The instructions the webpage gives to this are:

AirTime is a Full Free Software to provide Radio Automation Control with Linux.

To download it:

1. Open a LX Terminal session with administrator rights.
2. Type:

   ```
   wget http://apt.sourcefabric.org/misc/airtime-easy-setup.deb
   ```
3. Type:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i airtime-easy-setup.deb; sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. Install the software from the Lubuntu Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager.

Short history: It doesn't run (there was an error about dependencies).

I asked to Synaptic to uninstall the software, and it says it did it!!!

But... when I performed the steps 2 and 3 (LXTerminal session), there were a lot of items that had been installed or upgraded and nothing of that appeared when it had been uninstalled from Synaptic.

How could I be sure about all of that was uninstalled?

Is there a way to full uninstall all of that from the LXTerminal session?

Is there a way to know what is just "fill-a-blank-hole" in the system and remove it? ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the installed dependencies after removing AirTime, run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

This command removes all automatically installed packages, that are not longer needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! There should be a PDF file with all the possible commands to the LXTerminal sessions to avoid to have to ask here. I'll be waiting for it (maybe... someday...) Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: That's not a terminal thing. That's are commands for your shell, E.g. bash